# android sqlite database access raising lock error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android service from which am trying to access an sqlite database.The code is running ok but am having trouble accessing the database.I think the error has something to do with database lock.
Here is my methods from which am accessing the database:

```
private void checkWatchList() {
    Log.i("watch list", "watch list started");
    Cursor cursor;
    try {
        cursor = dbhandler.getAlerts();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.i("watch list", "checked");
                String share_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_SHARE_NAME));
                String max_price = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_MAX_PRICE));
                String min_price = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_MIN_PRICE));
                int action = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_ACTION));

                if (min_price.equals("NULL")) {
                    double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                    compareMax(share_name, maxprice, action);
                } else if (max_price.equals("NULL")) {
                    double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                    compareMin(share_name, minprice, action);
                } else {
                    double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                    double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                    compareMinMax(share_name, minprice, maxprice, action);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void compareMin(String sharename, double minprice, int action) {
    Log.i("compare min", "compare min");
    Cursor cursor;
    double new_price;
    String message = "The price is below minimum set price";
    try {
        cursor = dbhandler.compare(sharename);
        new_price = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));

        if (minprice <= new_price) {
            dbhandler.addTask(sharename, action, message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void compareMinMax(String sharename, double minprice,
        double maxprice, int action) {
    Log.i("compare minmax", "compare minmax");
    Cursor cursor;
    String message = "This price is below minimum set price.";
    try {
        cursor = dbhandler.compare(sharename);
        double new_price = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
        if (new_price <= minprice) {
            dbhandler.addTask(sharename, action, message);
        } else if (new_price >= maxprice) {
            dbhandler.addTask(sharename, action, message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void compareMax(String sharename, double maxprice, int action) {
    Log.i("compare max", "compare max");
    Cursor cursor;
    String message = "This price is more than maximum set price.";
    try {
        cursor = dbhandler.compare(sharename);
        double new_price = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));

        if (new_price >= maxprice) {
            dbhandler.addTask(sharename, action, message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the methods from the DatabaseHandler clas:

```
public Cursor getAlerts() {
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.query(TABLE_ALERTS, new String[] { KEY_SHARE_NAME,
            KEY_MIN_PRICE, KEY_MAX_PRICE, KEY_ACTION }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    database.close();
    return cursor;
}

public void addTask(String name, int action, String message) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_SHARENAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_TASK, action);
    values.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

    database.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
    database.close();
}

public Cursor compare(String sharename) {
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.query(TABLE_SHARES, new String[] { KEY_PRICE },
            KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { sharename }, null, null, null);
    database.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

From the output in the logcat,my code is running up until the checkWatchList method but is not executing the if condition in the loop.Here is the logcat output

```
09-11 13:11:15.289: I/watch list(22091): watch list started
09-11 13:11:15.319: W/System.err(22091): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.intelligent.stocktrader/databases/stocktrader.db (conn# 0) already closed
09-11 13:11:15.329: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
09-11 13:11:15.329: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:413)
09-11 13:11:15.329: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:400)
09-11 13:11:15.329: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
09-11 13:11:15.339: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:160)
09-11 13:11:15.339: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:152)
09-11 13:11:15.339: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:158)
09-11 13:11:15.349: W/System.err(22091):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:235)
09-11 13:11:15.349: W/System.err(22091):    at com.intelligent.stocktrader.database.ShareService.checkWatchList(ShareService.java:160)
09-11 13:11:15.349: W/System.err(22091):    at com.intelligent.stocktrader.database.ShareService.onCreate(ShareService.java:63)
09-11 13:11:15.359: W/System.err(22091):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2252)
09-11 13:11:15.359: W/System.err(22091):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:122)
09-11 13:11:15.359: W/System.err(22091):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
09-11 13:11:15.369: W/System.err(22091):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 13:11:15.369: W/System.err(22091):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 13:11:15.369: W/System.err(22091):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-11 13:11:15.369: W/System.err(22091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 13:11:15.379: W/System.err(22091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 13:11:15.379: W/System.err(22091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-11 13:11:15.379: W/System.err(22091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-11 13:11:15.379: W/System.err(22091):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 13:11:15.389: I/LocalService(22091): Received start id 1: Intent { cmp=com.intelligent.stocktrader/.database.ShareService }
```

Comment: this is because u are closing the database and then returning cursor. close the db in finally block.

Comment: @Vera how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can copy paste a portion of my code for u here :). Hope it is helpful.

```
        public zipAreas getzipArea(int zipAreaId) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = _dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        zipAreas zipArea = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[1];
        selectionArgs[0] = Integer.toString(zipAreaId);

        c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_zipAreaS + " where "
                + COLUMN_ID + " = ?", selectionArgs);

        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();

            zipArea = new zipAreas(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BIZ_AREA)));
        }

        return zipArea;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        CoreDataManager.handleException(new DatabaseException(e));
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (null != c)
            c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete database.close(); in your methods getAlerts and compare(String str)

```
 public Cursor getAlerts() {
        Cursor cursor;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_ALERTS, new String[] { KEY_SHARE_NAME,
                KEY_MIN_PRICE, KEY_MAX_PRICE, KEY_ACTION }, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public void addTask(String name, int action, String message) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SHARENAME, name);
        values.put(KEY_TASK, action);
        values.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        database.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor compare(String sharename) {
        Cursor cursor;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_SHARES, new String[] { KEY_PRICE },
                KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { sharename }, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

and look this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @kirylbelosh,i got a similar answer though.